# JavaScript - For what reason… Inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-5

Can someone tell me, please, for what reason this is allowed (?):

```
function A()
{
    A.prototype.getA = function()
    {
        return "A!";
    }
}

function B()
{
    B.prototype.getB = function()
    {
        return "B!";
    }
}

// Purposely placed here.
B.prototype = new A();

function SuperA()
{
    SuperA.prototype.getSuperA = function()
    {
        return "SUPER A!";
    }
}

A.prototype = new SuperA();

var objectB = new B();
alert(objectB.getA()); // A!
alert(objectB.getB()); // B!
alert(objectB.getSuperA()); // Error...
```

For what reason is permissible change a heritage structure, even in use? This change in inheritance structure should not be reflected?

Here is a possible / alleged inheritance among 3 types. Of course, the right thing to do would be to change the position of the statement "B.prototype = new A();", but I left that way on purpose.

Comment: Please be aware that every new instance of _A_, _B_ or _SuperA_ created here will modify the inheritance for all of their instances as you make a change to the prototype in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you can't declare the inheritance structure. All inheritance is done dynamically at runtime, so there is no point in time where it's no longer possible to change it.

When you use an instance of one class as a prottype for another, it's inheriting that instance, not just copying the structure. Example:

```
function A() {}
A.prototype = {
  hello: function() {}
};

var a = new A();

function B() {}
B.prototype = a;

var b = new B();

// all instances of B has the hello method
b.hello();

// add a method to the A instance
a.goodbye = function() {};

// now all instances of B have that method
b.goodbye();
```

Comment: It makes sense, after all the interpreter reads the code, and only functions are read and separated first. But I begin to confuse me when I think of objects. JavaScript uses objects. If I say that B inherits from A, and then I say A inherits from something, this should not be reflected by objects references? B does not have a structure of "A" updated? B does not know the structure of A, even if A is changed (in terms of Inheritance, in the case)?

Comment: @Loa: When you use an instance of A as prototype for B, then B isn't inheriting the structure of A, it's inheriting that instance of A. If you change the structure of A, or the content of that instance of A, it will affect all instances of B.

Comment: Hmm... Thank you. That cleared me some things. Would I being annoying if I asked you to show me an example of what you said now? Could you edit your answer or give me a link, please?

Comment: @Loa: I added an example above, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
 B.prototype = new A();
```

Says assign the prototype to an instance of A. 
If you leave out the constructor call, it's equivalent to this:

```
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
```

It means that `B.prototype` is pointing to an object cloned from `A.prototype`:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(B.prototype) === A.prototype // true
```

But then in this line:

```
A.prototype = new SuperA();
```

You are replacing the reference in `A.prototype` but `B.prototype` still points to the old one:

```
var oldProto = A.prototype;
A.prototype = new SuperA();
Object.getPrototypeOf(B.prototype) === A.prototype // false
Object.getPrototypeOf(B.prototype) === oldProto    // true
```

This line works:

```
alert(objectB.getA());
```

Because `getA` was added in the `new A()` call, so it adds a new slot to the existing prototype, instead of replacing the whole instance.

And this:

```
alert(objectB.getSuperA());
```

Doesn't work because SuperA is not in the prototype chain of B.

This problem is very tricky. But actually JavaScript has a very simple model, but confusing by some of the language keywords (new/instanceof), and the strange use of functions (to resemble Java constructors):

- Property/method lookup always goes up in the prototype chain. That's all the inheritance that you have.
- "Clonning" (in terms of Object.create) means to create a new empty object, and set the prototype from the given object.
- Prototypes are just reference to objects, so you can add/change slots at any time.

With only those two things you don't need the rest. And constructors -with some small internal differences- can be seen as a shortcut to:

```
var newInstance = Object.create(SomeFunction.prototype);
SomeFunction.constructor.apply(newInstance, arguments);
```

To me the use of functions to create objects was a bad idea, if JavaScript only had `Object.create` from version 1 and no constructor functions, all the model is much easier to understand.